# reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler deprecated in iOS7 but replacement not specified

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center

Has anyone found the replacement for

`[GKAchievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler]`?

Typically when things are deprecated the docs indicate a replacement.  Not so with this one so far and I wanted to cross this off the list of possible causes of another issue we are seeing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was looking for the same info and saw your post, here is what I went with after not finding anything either:

```
NSArray *achievements = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:achievement, nil];
[GKAchievement reportAchievements:achievements withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
   if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
   }
}];
```

Comment: Good find, apparently iOS likes this better.  I suppose they would prefer a single call for numerous achievements rather than one for each... probably some network optimization.

Answer (score 0):

This works in iOS7 with no issues.

```
- (void)checkAchievements
{
    if(myScore >= 25000){
            GKAchievement *achievement= [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Achiev1"];
            achievement.percentComplete = 100.0;
            achievement.showsCompletionBanner = YES;
            [self Achievements:achievement];

        }
}

-(void)Achievements:(GKAchievement*)achievement {

    NSArray *achievements = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:achievement, nil];
    [GKAchievement reportAchievements:achievements withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
        }
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is apple's full code (same/similar to Silly Goose's Answer)

```
- (void) completeMultipleAchievements
{
    GKAchievement *achievement1 = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"DefeatedFinalBoss"];
    GKAchievement *achievement2 = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"FinishedTheGame"];
    GKAchievement *achievement3 = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"PlayerIsAwesome"];
    achievement1.percentComplete = 100.0;
    achievement2.percentComplete = 100.0;
    achievement3.percentComplete = 100.0;

    NSArray *achievementsToComplete = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:achievement1,achievement2,achievement3, nil];
    [GKAchievement reportAchievements: achievementsToComplete withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
             {
                  if (error != nil)
                  {
                      NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
                  }
             }];
      }
```